# Which is more efficient for Selecting records that 'happened' - from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 of a date in a another record, in the same JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to fetch data for records for a given date/ 1 day interval.

This means from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59` of that day. The date value comes from another table in a join statement... i.e, it's not a parameter.

Suppose I have a `Transactions` table with a `DateOccured` (`Datetime`) field

From my research, I have two possible options(amongst others).

1. **Calculate the datetime range values for that day**

   From `00:00:00`

   DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,Transaction.DateOccured,0)

   To `23:59:59`

   DateAdd(dd, 1, DateAdd(ss, -1, CONVERT(DATE,Transaction.DateOccured))) -- 1 second before midnight of following day

(several options of doing this, e.g placing this in the `SELECT` list or placing it in the `WHERE` clause)

2. **Convert `Datetime` to date then append appropriate strings(for the time portion) to create the range** (does not seem efficient)

Which would be the best strategy?

Would I place this calculation in the `SELECT` list and use as a field in the `WHERE`? or is it better of in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: So, you want to exclude anything that happened *during* the last minute of the day (e.g. with a time stamp of `23:59:59.327`)? It's almost always easier/simpler/correct to use an *exclusive* end point (e.g. midnight at the start of the following day)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *simplest* method is:

```
on cast(t.dateoccurred as date) = t2.otherdate
```

This could use an index on the first table (see Martin Smith's comment).  It can definitely take advantage of an index on the second table.

The following version could also use an index on the first table but not the second:

```
on t.dateocurred >= t2.otherdate and
   t.dateoccurred < dateadd(day, 1, t2.otherdate)
```

Comment: I assume this is in the JOIN condition. Not sure I understand why there is a `t2` table. The date range would be determined by a single datetime  column of the second table. i.e records for the day of `t2.DateTimeOccured` i.e. using psuedo-SQL: getting the date range `t2.DateTime + '00:00:00'` to `t2.DateTime + 'DateTime' + '23:59:59'`

Comment: In my experience, SQL Server uses indices just fine when filtering by `cast(as date)` In many cases it even manages to use an index in `where datediff(d, col1, col2) = 0`.

Comment: Wait...How did you edit your answer without leaving an edit trail?... Is that a rank priviledge?...Thanks anyways. Marking as answer.

Comment: @user919426 . . . The original answer ended at the second paragraph.  I realized that you might want to use an index on the *first* table.  I must've added that part within the five minute count-down, so it is not recorded as an official edit.

Comment: @GSerg It can use an index but is still somewhat suboptimal http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Thank you for the reference.  Now, I just have to remember it ;)